# Printing Locally Stored Photos in Adobe Flex/Air

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, printing, air, adobe

In my Adobe Flex/Air application I have an ArrayCollection storing a list of details (including the file path) for locally stored photographs.

What would be the best way to print all these photos from within the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution consists of two steps:

1. **Load images**. It can be done by using [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html). It can load images by local path or URL.
2. **Print images**. Flex have appropriate class for printing - [FlexPrintJob](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/printing/FlexPrintJob.html). It can print any UIComponent (Bitmap too).

I did not write all the code, but there are examples in the documentation and there is not any magic =). But if you have question feel free to ask.